# Privilege endpoint for UI in REST application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application with REST (Spring MVC) backend and pure JavaScript frontend. Recently we enabled security via spring security and we are discussing *How to tell UI what privileges user has*, i.e. *what controls should be presented to the user according to her roles*.

For what I tried:

- We may just expose and endpoint with list of authorities (roles) and let UI deal with it. This is simple for backend but then in our backend we maintain ROLE -> Allowed URLs mappings and same will happen on frontend. At some point these will diverge (I'm sure!) and we will show an UI control which - when used - will result in `403 - Unauthorized`.
- Make it URL centric because that's what REST is: Have an endpoint (say: `/security/privileges?url=...&method=...`) which answers question: *Am I allowed to access URL x via Request method y?* This will allow the UI to focus on URLs only which seems to be nicer. But looks like nightmare/impossible for backend (specially when you combine web security through filters with method level security through `@Pre/@Post` annotations.

Questions:

1. I'm looking on best practices how to approach communicating user privileges from REST backend to UI. Should it be URL centric or just send list of roles?
2. If anyone went through URL centric approach is there a way how to examine controller's methods for whether is will pass security checks? Note that [WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/WebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.html) is not enought as it doesn't take into account method level security.

**EDIT:**
To clarify my doubts about approach with sending list of roles. If I do that then:

MVC controller:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'EDITOR'")
@RequestMapping("/editStuff")
public void editStuff(...) {
   ...
}
```

JS:

```
if (hasRole('ADMIN') || hasRole('EDITOR')) {
    showEditControllWhichOnClickCalls('/editStuff');
}
```

There is clearly duplicated check for having any of roles *EDITOR* or *ADMIN*. If you on the other hand do in JS (and ideally maintain the URL as a constant in one place) it looks less coupled to me:

```
if (doIHaveAccessTo('/editStuff', 'POST')) {
    showEditControllWhichOnClickCalls('/editStuff');
}
```

Comment: _"Should it be URL centric or just send list of roles"_ A list of roles. URLs are for from being sufficient. _"At some point these will diverge"_ == _"At some point my code will contain bugs"_ -> That' why you have automated tests.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Duplicated code which must be maintained in two places is to me not the same as bug. I'll add a clarification of my doubts about sending list of roles.

Comment: I suggest to take another point view. Forget the backend and imagine it is provided by someone else. Which is the case for any public API. How would you prefer to incorporate security in your client app? Btw: I hope now you can see that if you only develop a client application, then failing to include an existing role is a bug. URLs are definitely not enough. You may have the right to read, but not to write, the right for media type A, but not B. All of that has implications for the UI ...

Comment: ... But you could provide a structure containing URL, allowed methods and - if necessary - media types. Or just provide permissions: `if (canEditStuff)`. So 3 roles vs. long list of URLs and stuff ...

Answer (score 0):

Fronted:
 Afer login you should recive UserDetails object with all Roles and Privliges related to logged in user. Based on this information you can decide, what control on your UI you should hide or show.

Backend:
 You can use any SSO system to keep your user authenticated after successfull login. Sessions, remember-me token, doesn't matter. It just asociates all your requests with Authentication object in SecurityContext and allow you to manage access right to different sevices. About tokens you can read there:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html

Ask any concrete questions, I'll try to answer